# WPF C# delete listbox item based on content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I have a list box and I need to modify the list based on the content. I am trying to do this but it does not do any thing.

```
string itemRemove =   "Apple";
lstFruits.Items.Remove(itemRemove);
```

Comment: What is `lstFruits`? What happens when you run the code? It seems fine to me - if there is an `Apple` item in your list, it will be removed. But please be more clear with your question.

Comment: lstFruits is a list box control and apple is an item . It is not removing the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in a `ListBox` control, you cant remove an item like you remove them from `List<T>`(i.e using an enumerator). You have to you have to loop using an index, starting at the last item, like this :

```
for (int n = lstFruits.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
{
    string itemRemove = "Apple";
    if (lstFruits.Items[n].ToString().Contains(itemRemove))
    {
        lstFruits.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
}
```